# Android Activity (Application) lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

So Im currently creating an app on android studio and was getting this one bug, but I don't really understand the issue. So currently I am implementing a sharedPreference to store my user login session so that the user does not have to keep logging in if he already has. But the issue is, when I back out of the main launcher(main activity) and come back to the app it goes to the main activity but none of the buttons work.

I was looking around and found that maybe the I needed to implement a better flow of the app lifecyle (onResume, onPause ... ). Now I have created other apps like a weather app but none of them have the implementation of those methods. So i was wondering if someone who has encountered this issue can help me find a concrete solution to my issue.

I might be totally wrong with what the solution is but here's my code for the main activity onCreate method. Maybe something's wrong there

```
  @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
      ActionBar bar=getSupportActionBar();
      bar.hide();

    // get notifications from the updated months
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    Date date = new Date();
    //Log.d("Month",dateFormat.format(date));
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    String curMonth = months[currentMonth];
    // sends the notification for when new apples are in season
    if(dateFormat.format(date) == curMonth){
        notificationSetter();
    }
    // initializing user's session
    session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());

    //this will check if the user is logged in. if not: redirected to MainLogin

    session.checkLogin();
    HashMap<String,String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    if(user.get(UserSession.KEY_NAME) == null)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainLogin.class);
        // these flags are added to make the login activity be the front of our app. so when you
        // press the back button, it goes to the home page of the phone
        // saying that login activity should be new task and the old task should be cleared
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    Bundle appleData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (appleData == null)
        return;
    currentTable = appleData.getString("username");
    Log.e("current", currentTable);



    // search button
    mSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    mSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, SearchActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", currentTable);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // inSeason button
    inSeason = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seasonButton);
    inSeason.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, Apple_Season_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", currentTable);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // basket button
    basketButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.basketButton);
    basketButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, FavoriteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("username", currentTable);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Probably it is because you are creating a new UserSession each time the activity encounters the onCreate() method. Maybe you should check whether there exists a UserSession and if not then only create the a new UserSession.

Comment: Something like if(session != null){ session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());// Set session variables here} else{ session.checkLogin();}